How to access "selectors" from a slice in redux toolkit
So, I'm still new to redux toolkit and I'm likely doing some of this wrong. In any case, I'm curious how to extract my "selectors" from my store/slice in redux.
Let's say I have the following slice:
const mySlice = creatSlice({
    name: 'my-slice',
    initialState: {
      stuff: {
        primary: 'Things',
        secondary: 'Other Things',
      },
    },
    reducers: (create) => ({
      getStuff: create.asyncThunk(
        () => getSomeDataAsynchronously(),
        { ...justAssumeTheseUpdateStateWithData },
      ),
    }), 
    // this is the part I'm most interested in understanding better
    // I'm not even sure I'm doing it right. Is this how to handle
    // using arguments, or do I need to curry or something?
    selectors: {
      selectStuff: (state) => state.stuff,
      selectSpecificStuff: (state, key) => state[key] ?? 'not found',
    }
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: mySlice.reducer
});

So here's where I'm most confused. Let's assume I've injected that store in my Provider, and I'm on a child react component:
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const selectSpecificStuff = useSelector(/* how to access from my slice? */);

  return <>{selectSpecificStuff('primary')}</>;
}

Is this even possible? I can't seem to find anything about it in the docs, which makes me wonder what the point of the selectors property is, if you can't access it.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Defining & Accessing the Selectors

I'm curious how to extract my "selectors" from my store/slice in
redux.

The selectors are extracted just like the generated actions are.
Example:
export const {
  selectStuff,
  selectSpecificStuff
} = myslice.selectors;

The selectSpecificStuff selector is still working with the slice's state, so it would need to access state.stuff first.
selectors: {
  selectStuff: (state) => state.stuff,
  selectSpecificStuff: (state, key) => state.stuff[key] ?? "not found"
}

or
selectors: {
  selectStuff: (state) => state.stuff,
  selectSpecificStuff: (state, key) => {
    const stuff = mySlice.getSelectors().selectStuff(state);
    return stuff[key] ?? "not found";
  }
}

Using the Selectors

So here's where I'm most confused. Let's assume I've injected that
store in my Provider, and I'm on a child react component:
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const selectSpecificStuff = useSelector(/* how to access from my slice? */);

  return <>{selectSpecificStuff('primary')}</>;
}

Is this even possible? I can't seem to find anything about it in the
docs, which makes me wonder what the point of the selectors property
is, if you can't access it.

The part that initially tripped me up with these selectors is that they are generated expecting to be mounted/injected into the store using their defined reducerPath value, which defaults to the slice's name property by default.
Example:
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'my-slice', // <-- default reducer path
  initialState: {
    stuff: {
      primary: 'Things',
      secondary: 'Other Things',
    },
  },
  reducers: (create) => ({
    ....
  }), 
  selectors: {
    selectStuff: (state) => state.stuff,
    selectSpecificStuff: (state, key) => state.stuff[key] ?? "not found"
  }
});

export const {
  selectStuff,
  selectSpecificStuff
} = myslice.selectors;

...

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    "my-slice": mySlice.reducer // <-- mount under correct path
  }
});


Import the selectors, and in the useSelector hook callback pass the root state and the key argument to the slice selector.
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectStuff, selectSpecificStuff } from '../path/to/mySlice';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const stuff = useSelector(selectStuff);
  const primaryStuff = useSelector((state) =>
    selectSpecificStuff(state, "primary")
  );
  const secondaryStuff = useSelector((state) =>
    selectSpecificStuff(state, "secondary")
  );
  const tertiaryStuff = useSelector((state) =>
    selectSpecificStuff(state, "tertiary")
  );

  console.log({
    stuff:          // { stuff: { primary: "Things", secondary: "Other Things" } }
    primaryStuff,   // "Things"
    secondaryStuff, // "Other Things"
    tertiaryStuff,  // "not found"
  });

  ...
}


Alternative Selector Usage
getSelectors
Using mySlice.getSelectors() is the other way to access the selectors.
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: mySlice.reducer
});

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import mySlice from '../path/to/mySlice';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const stuff = useSelector(mySlice.getSelectors().selectStuff);
  const primaryStuff = useSelector((state) =>
    mySlice.getSelectors().selectSpecificStuff(state, "primary")
  );
  const secondaryStuff = useSelector((state) =>
    mySlice.getSelectors().selectSpecificStuff(state, "secondary")
  );
  const tertiaryStuff = useSelector((state) =>
    mySlice.getSelectors().selectSpecificStuff(state, "tertiary")
  );

  console.log({
    stuff:          // { stuff: { primary: "Things", secondary: "Other Things" } }
    primaryStuff,   // "Things"
    secondaryStuff, // "Other Things"
    tertiaryStuff,  // "not found"
  });

  ...
}


Slight correction - getSelectors() will still assume your slice state at state[reducerPath], but you can use it to override the path by doing getSelectors(state => state.path.to.slice)

@phry Interesting. The getSelectors appeared to access the correct state in spite of the reducer not having the assumed path. Perhaps I'm still misunderstanding something from the docs though. Please feel free to suggest an appropriate edit so the correct information is made available.

@phry Ah, is it this specifically, "If no selectState callback is passed, selectors will be returned as is - expecting the slice state as their first parameter (the same as calling slice.getSelectors(state => state))." - So it just happened to work "correctly" because the reducer is also the root state?

Ah, my bad, it's an identity function, not looking for reducerPath. But yeah, it's useful for "inside" other selectors, but it won't magically know where your slice is mounted in other cases.

Thank you, this definitely helped me figure out more of what was going on. Maybe it's just a style issue for me, but I find the redux docs extremely difficult to read.

@CStroliaDavis For the most part I find the Redux docs pretty straight-forward and thorough, but RTKv2 introduced quite a bunch of new features that I don't think have been documented well (yet). Even I had to basically create a sandbox and test these new selectors myself and kind of figure it out through trial-and-error to see how they worked. I think the documentation will be improved.

@DrewReese, yes, I think I meant to say Redux Toolkit docs, and it turns out they are pretty thorough, except that the organization of the information leaves a lot to be desired and can make it really difficult to understand what's going on.
Also, I think some of RTKs opinionated architecture could use a bit of a change of opinion, as I don't think the new format is actually easier to use than the old one, even though it does simplify some things. Of course, I'm using TypeScript and that seems to be the biggest challenge for me with this.

I haven't tried selectors inside createSlice(). However, without those entries, the following should work:
const sliceOfInterest = useSelector(state => state['my-slice']);

and now, you can access
sliceOfInterest.stuff.primary, etc.

Obviously, you have to check for stuff not being null.
Also, export your actions so you can call them from elsewhere
// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { getStuff } = mySlice.actions;

You don't need "get" reducer functions though. Have your reducer functions to edit/modify your global state. Access them using the useSelector shown above.
If you had other reducer functions (in the code area where getSuff is), you will call them this way:
dispatch(getStuff(params))

